# ImageView doesn't wrap content in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, alignment, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a TableLayout with 6 childs/entrys. These childs are a custom RelativeLayout. In each RelativeLayout is a big TextView in the middle and an ImageView and small TextView at the bottom.

The ImageView should be as tall as the TextView next to it. That's why I set the attribute ALIGN_TOP and ALIGN_BOTTOM to the TextView (you can see it in code below). This works very well and both - ImageView and TextView - have the same height now. But the problem is, that the left and right side of the ImageView don't "wrap content" anymore (as you can see on the screenshot).

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to fit the left and right side to the image and remove the "padding"?

Here is my code:

**view_display_component.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >   
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplayBig"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_extra_large" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewDisplayIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvDisplayBig"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/stopwatch_64"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplaySmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small" />                
</merge>
```

**class DisplayComponent which extends RelativLayout**

```
public DisplayComponent(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_display_component, this, true);
    tvDisplay = (TextView) getChildAt(0);
    icon = (ImageView) getChildAt(1);
    tvName = (TextView) getChildAt(2);

    setupAlign();
}

private void setupAlign() {
    if(index % 2 == 0) {    // LEFT SIDE
       // same as "RIGHT SIDE"
    } else {        // RIGHT SIDE
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsIcon = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) icon.getLayoutParams();
        paramsIcon.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        paramsIcon.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, tvName.getId());
        paramsIcon.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, tvName.getId());
        icon.setLayoutParams(paramsIcon);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTvName = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tvName.getLayoutParams();
        paramsTvName.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, icon.getId()); 
        tvName.setLayoutParams(paramsTvName);

        tvName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); // only for testing
        icon.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }
```

Comment: Does your original image of that alarm clock have that padding?

Comment: One solution could be try giving width and height to your imageview and change your scaleType to fitXY.

Comment: No, the ImageView has no padding, I tested it with setting "icon.setPadding(0,0,0,0)".
The problem with your solution is, that I can't get the width/height of the ImageView or TextView. The call "getHeight" or "getMeasuredHeight" returns always the value 0. I think it's too early to get the size of a view in the constructor.

(Btw, the icons original size is 64x64 px.)

Comment: Try this instead of layout_width and height for the imageview set as wrap_content, set it as 64 dip. And see what happens.

Comment: No, nothing changed. Same result as before. There must be a way to set aign_top/align_bottom and the ImageView resizes the align_left/align_right for it self...

Comment: Did you removed android:adjustViewBounds="true" after making the changes. layout_width and layout_height should be 64 dip and scale type should be fitXY. Nothing changed?

Comment: Yes, I did all changes. The border of ImageView is still too large. The only thing that changed is that the icon is scaled in y-direction now (because of fitXY).

Comment: Btw, if I add negativ padding for image (for exaple -20dp right and left) then the ImageView wraps more the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an (ugly) solution. Because my icon is square, I created a custom ImageView and overrode the onSizeChanged() method like this:

```
public class IconImageView extends ImageView {

    public IconImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if(h != oldh && h > 0)
            getLayoutParams().width = h;  // same width as height
    }
}
```

But this works only if the image is square. That's why I am still searching for a better solution. Maybe some layout solution with a better setting of alignment.

Best regards!